# Como realizar pago con paypal en modo produccion

Tags: c#, paypal

Hola inclui Paypal como solucion para pago de los clientes en mi web .Net MVC

Hice todo como la guia, y para las cuentas sandbox o testing me funciona ok, el problema viene cuando pase la variable mode a live o produccion.

En mi web.config

```
  <paypal>
 <settings>     
  <add name="mode" value="live" />
  <add name="connectionTimeout" value="360000" />
 
  <add name="clientId" value="myclientid" />
  <add name="clientSecret" value="myclientsecret" />
</settings>
</paypal>

   public static Dictionary<string, string> GetConfig()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dictionary.Add("clientId",paypalsetup.clientId);
        dictionary.Add("clientSecret", paypalsetup.clientSecret);          
        dictionary.Add("mode", "live");
        return dictionary;        
    }

 private static string GetAccessToken()
  {
       
   OAuthTokenCredential tokenCredential = new OAuthTokenCredential(ClientId, ClientSecret, 
   GetConfig());
        string accessToken = tokenCredential.GetAccessToken();
        return accessToken;
  }
```

Aqui el problema es cuando llamo al metodo GetAccessToken Error 401 no autorizado, no se porque en modo sandbox  me fuciona bien y en modo live me genera ese problema, alguien tiene alguna idea?. por favor

Comment: Nunca lo use, pero lo normal es que vos tengas un token para pruebas y luego uno para produccion y tendrias que cambiarlo.

Comment: ¿Tu sitio tiene httpS ?